# Deploying Kong on dedicated Server with Plesk, adding port at the end of the url

Tags: networking, deployment, plesk, api-gateway, kong

I am using Kong as an API Gateway and Keycloak for authentication services. I have a dedicated Linux server, and I am using Plesk for server management. I run all services in Docker Compose. I created a subdomain and made port forwarding from Kong Container to my subdomain. My problem is this: When I try to reach Keyclaok, I use this URL. https://.domain>/auth, but it redirects me to the https://. :8000/auth. Because the Kong service is already forwarded to the URL, I don't need the port.  I could not solve this problem. Anyone who has had a similar experience I drop my kong.yml and docker-compose files here.  I deleted passwords and sensitive data.

kong.yaml

```
_format_version: "1.1"

services:
  - name: keycloak_auth
    host: keycloak
    protocol: http

    port: 8080
    routes:
      - name: keycloak-route
        paths:
          - /auth
        strip_path: false
        preserve_host: true

  - name: frontend
    host: frontend
    protocol: http

    port: 3001
    routes:
      - name: frontend_route
        paths:
          - /
        strip_path: false
        preserve_host: true

  - name: backend
    host: backend
    protocol: http

    port: 9999
    routes:
      - name: backend_route
        paths:
          - /backend
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: backend
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ./development-entrypoint.sh
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 9001:9999
    environment:
   
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kong

  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_DB=

    volumes:
      - ./docker_postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker_postgres_init.sql
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  kong:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/kong/Dockerfile.kong
    container_name: api_gateway
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
      - "8445:8443"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
    volumes:
      - ./kong/kong.yml:/kong.yml
      - ./kong/kong.conf:/etc/kong/kong.conf
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: "off"
      KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG: kong.yml
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_LOG_LEVEL: warn
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl, 0.0.0.0:9080 http2, 0.0.0.0:9081 http2 ssl
      KONG_PLUGINS: oidc
      KC_HTTPS_PORT: 8445

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=
      - DB_ADDR=
      - DB_DATABASE=
      - DB_USER=
      - DB_PASSWORD=
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=
      - KC_PROXY=
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  frontend:
    image: frontend
    container_name: frontend

    ports:
      - 3334:3001
      - 9228:9229
    command: ["node", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "index.js"]
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I have tried to change the different combination  of strip_path and preserve_host. It did not really work. I have added this line in kong.conf, but it did not help either. proxy_listen = 0.0.0.0:8000,<domain_name>:80